# concatenating 2 list in python

Tags: python, string, list

this is what I have. I want to concatenate this 2 list together

```
first_name = ['Homer', 'Marge', 'Bart', 'Lisa', 'Maggie',
'Carl', 'Ned', 'Barney', 'Lenny', 'Otto', 'Seymour']

last_name = ['Simpson', 'Simpson', 'Simpson', 'Simpson', 'Simpson',
'Carlson', 'Flanders', 'Gumble', 'Leonard', 'Mann', 'Skinner']

for (i, j) in zip(first_name, last_name):
    print (first_name[i] + " " + last_name[j])
```

But there is an error message saying

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

on the line with the "print" statement

Comment: You're actually merging lists with zip, not concatenating

Comment: When you tried to find the error yourself and used `print(i, j)` in the loop for that, what did you see?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your loop actually iterates through the elements, not the indices

```
for (f, l) in zip(first_name, last_name):
    print (f + " " + l)
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** in case of using indexes, but iterating through elemenets is better

The two lists have same length so:

```
for i in range(len(first_name)):
    print(first_name[i] + " "  + last_name[j])
```

Comment: That is actually not the recommended way of writing Python code: You should try and iterate through lists instead of finding ways to generate list indices. That's the reason for `zip`s existence.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python [map function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) in the following way to get the output you want:

```
print(map(lambda f,l: f + " " + l, first_name, last_name))
```